# Any way to selectively disable ColdFusion's built-in form validation?

Tags: coldfusion, validation

I am working with some old code. It uses built-in ColdFusion form validation (i.e. `_required` hidden fields). I want to add a cancel button to the form. The cancel button has to actually handle some business logic (so I can't just make it set location.href to some other page). Problem is that, because the cancel button is a submit button, it triggers that built-in validation and the user gets an error that the field is required.

Is there any way to disable the validation for that particular submit button? I'd rather not try to modify the underlying code which builds the form, as it is used in a bunch of places. Here is a greatly simplified version of my code:

```
<cfif IsDefined("Form.OK")>
  You clicked OK!
<cfelseif IsDefined("Form.Cancel")>
  You clicked Cancel!
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
  <form action="#CGI.Path_Info#" method="POST">
    Enter Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Name_required" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="OK" value="OK" />
    <input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
  </form>
</cfoutput>
```

One thing that I thought of is to make the onclick of the Cancel button remove any hidden "_required" fields from the DOM. This works, but it feels very hacky. Here's the Javascript I used for that approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function removeRequiredFields() {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i <= els.length; i++) {
      if(els[i].type == 'hidden' && els[i].name.endsWith('_required'))
        els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: (btw, your workaround might also want to inspect `textarea` and `select` tags?)

Comment: Ultimately, the best (and easiest) solution might be to actually change the code that generates the form. While the JS solution to remove those fields might work, it does seem 'hacky'. How will you handle having the JS be executed? Wouldn't that need to be added to the code that generates the form anyway?

Comment: Does the Cancel actually need to submit the form?  What if you changed the Cancel button from a `submit` type to a `button` type and handle it's processing via the onclick event?

Answer (score 5):

CF9+ - Application.cfc

```
this.serverSideFormValidation="false";
```

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/7/12/My-first-ColdFusion-9-scoop--disable-server-side-validation

CF8 - Application.cfc

```
<cfset this.name = "myApplication">
<cfset url.form = structnew()/>
<cfset structappend(url.form,form)/>
<cfset structclear(form)/>
<cffunction name="onRequestStart">
    <cfset structappend(form,url.form)/>
    <cfset structdelete(url,"form")/>
</cffunction>
```

http://www.cfinsider.com/index.cfm/2008/9/30/Getting-Around-ColdFusion-Form-Validation

Comment: but this disables it for the whole application... i'm just wanting it disabled for a specific button

Comment: Wow, didn't know about either of those. **Kip**: If you disable it completely, you can re-implement it yourself properly (it's not at all complicated). Also: you are aware, I hope, that having validation driven by form field names is still just as insecure as client-side validation... If you don't already have _proper_ server-side validation, your app likely has security holes.

Comment: Having said that, to do it selectively you can probably do: `<cfif StructKeyExists(Form,'Cancel')><cfset this.serverSideFormValidation = false /></cfif>` - but really you should be fixing it properly.

Comment: Have you tested that?  I've found that changing application settings normally set in the application.cfc pseudo constructor don't like to be changed after the fact

Comment: @Travis Every request runs the code in Application.cfc pseudo constructor so it should be fine.  Unless it is cached somehow, restart CF instance to be sure.

Comment: It's unfortunate code like that would have to go into the application.cfc when it applies to a small part of the website.